# PowerShell string manipulation

Tags: powershell, dns

I have a requirement to find DNS registered hostname of a given IP via PowerShell. 
Could someone please tell me how can I store computer name alone (“mysystem” in below example) to a variable from below output.

```
$Hostname = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($ipAddress)

HostName                 Aliases         AddressList                                                 
--------                 -------         -----------                                                 
mysystem.mycountry.company.com         {}              {fe80::50d6:7029:f655:f955%11,
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple. In PowerShell, the return results are always objects. The column headings in the return results (or labels, of the return results are in list format) are properties of the object that's returned. So instead of assigning the whole object to **$Hostname**, just assign the object's **HostName** property:

```
$Hostname = ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($ipAddress)).HostName
```

Answer (score 1):

Take just the `HostName` property and split it at dots:

```
$Hostname = ([Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($ipAddress).HostName -split '\.')[0]
```

Comment: Ah, yes...I overlooked the part about wanting just the first part, not the whole FQDN. So this answer is more complete.